# No output after curl request

Tags: curl, https, request

I am making a requests to the Aconex api, however nothing outputs.

The documentation for getting started on the API is on this website 
https://help.aconex.com/aconex/aconex-apis/getting-started-aconex-apis/getting-started-apis

I used their api query tool and able to make a successful requests, unlike the git bash.

```
curl -u user:password https://uk1.aconex.co.uk/api/projects/268441564/mail?mail_box=inbox
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you did not encode the user:password to base 64.